# Remove title generated in Typo3

Tags: typo3, title

I am having trouble with Typo3, the previous developer added a word at the end of the title tag in each page, but I can't find where. I need to remove it.

Basically the text you put in Edit Page Properties/Subtitle is used and :Example is appended at the end of the title.

I searched in the files for that :Example word and it isn't there.

I also went to Template/Root page/Setup and it isn't there, there isn't even a mention of headerData. There is no template Voila.

The only hint I have is that the :Example is also the name of the site. So it can be an option to add :NameOfTheSite, but I don't know where to find it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the addition to the title tag is made by a wrap via TypoScript.

Try the typoscript ObjectBrowser, to find the entry (Backend: Web->Template select TypoScript Object Browser in the Dropdown).
headerData is the position where I would expect the addition to be made.

Where you can change it depends on, how your TS is included. Do you have Backend Records of TypoScript or do you include files?

A Hotfix can be done directly, using the ObjectBrowser - you can edit an entry there. But this should not be the final solution, because the ObjectBrowser creates a new Template Record in the database.

Comment: I followed the second item of this blog and it fixed it.
Thanks anyway.
http://www.dawsoninteractive.com/articles/article/typo3-seo-part-1-title-tags/